# Can Bokeh detect screen size and reshape the layout for mobile?

Tags: python, bokeh

I finished my bokeh app and display well on PC. However, the mobile screen is too small to display my plot with texts on the right side. Is there a way that bokeh can detect screen size and adjust my layout or text size? For example when mobile display I would want my text below my plot , so my plot can be bigger. Thank you.

Comment: after detecting the screen size you need to fix your layout/text size

Comment: So I wrote code like, it did not work.  
```import pyautogui
screen_size = pyautogui.size()

if screen_size[0] >= 1280: 
  #layout 
  layout = row(p, column(div_help, select, div_reference))   
else: 
  #layout 
  layout = column(p, div_help, select, div_reference)

# Add the plot to the current document
curdoc().add_root(layout)  ```